# Is that possible to make custom renderscript intrinsics?

Tags: intrinsics, renderscript

Renderscript intrinsics is very fast and useful. However, there are situations where we might want to build our own intrinsics, e.g. current convolution doesn't support the "valid" mode as in matlab. It would be very nice to have it. So, I'm wondering if it's possible to do so and connect nicely with the java layer (just like the existing intrinsics)? If it's possible, would you sketch how? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, there's no way to add custom intrinsics right now. in the next release we're planning to add support for clipped intrinsics in the same way that clipped kernels operate since 4.3, which would allow you to add a valid mode equivalent to Matlab.

Comment: Can you please tell the Renderscript developers to create more tutorials and various samples ? Also, can you please add some IDE support for writing the scripts themselves?