# Custom renderscript is slower than intrinsic

Tags: android, android-camera2, renderscript

I have a simple custom renderscript to convert NV21 to RGB bitmap:

```c
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

rs_allocation NV21;
uint32_t Yline;
uint32_t UVline;
uint32_t Width;
uint32_t Height;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) NV21toRGB(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    uint32_t Vidx = Yline*Height + (x & ~1) + y/2 * UVline;
    short Y = rsGetElementAt_uchar(NV21, x + y * Yline);
    short V = rsGetElementAt_uchar(NV21, Vidx) - 128;
    short U = rsGetElementAt_uchar(NV21, Vidx + 1) - 128;

    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#JPEG_conversion
    short R = Y + (512           + 1436 * V) / 1024; //             1.402
    short G = Y + (512 -  352 * U - 731 * V) / 1024; // -0.344136  -0.714136
    short B = Y + (512 + 1815 * U          ) / 1024; //  1.772

    if (R < 0) R = 0; else if (R > 255) R = 255;
    if (G < 0) G = 0; else if (G > 255) G = 255;
    if (B < 0) B = 0; else if (B > 255) B = 255;
    return (uchar4){R, G, B, 255};
}
```

The motivation for this script is that `ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB` uses the *video* [BT.610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.601_conversion) color space (where **Y** is in range `[16…235]`).

The results are satisfactory, but on my device (Nokia 4.2 with Android 10), it is about twice slower than the intrinsic script: average `9` *vs.* `18 ms` for 1920x1080. Both scripts use the same input and output allocations.

All times were measured on Release Arm64 build. It's worth to mention that the shortest time is `11 ms`. An experiment shows that both retrieving YUV and conversion calculation could be optimized: if I simply return `rsYuvToRGBA_uchar4(Y, U, V)`, the average time is down to `14 ms`.

*Question*: is there some way I can further improve my custom script? E.g., Tim Murray [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20526586/192373) ***custom intrinsics*** in 2013, but I even in 2020 don't know how these could be defined.

***Update***: thanks [AccoGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7335974/accoguy), I tried these two renderscripts with/without `debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1` (see [comment commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/c83dd0b9f81aaeb15e2d03849b04f20b581bfe49)). The results are amazing:

With the intrinsic convertor, the time is `4 ms` for conversion itself (`ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.ForEach()`), plus `5 ms` for the innocent `outputAllocation.copyTo(output)`.
When I disable GPU (`adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1`), the time is `3 ms` plus `1 ms`.

With the custom script, on disabled GPU the time is between `13 ms` and `30 ms`, but on average `~19 ms` for conversion (plus same `1 ms` for copy).

The unexpected part is that when GPU is enabled, the time is split as <s>`2 ms` for conversion and **`18 ms`**</s> *(wrong because I forgot about [asynchronous nature of forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63962361/custom-renderscript-is-slower-than-intrinsic?noredirect=1#comment113266736_63962361))*;
*Fixed:* `14 ms` for conversion and `7 ms` for `outputAllocation.copyTo(output)`.

The pattern holds on other devices, and may be even stronger. E.g. a Sony with Snapdragon 835 runs the intrinsic RS in `1 ms`, custom RS in `4 ms`. Allocation copy after the intrinsic script is `2 ms`, after custom RS it's `4 ms`.

I don't have a clue how this could happen, or what can be done to improve it.

Comment: I don't get the mid part. If you simply return rsYuvToRGBA_uchar4(Y, U, V) the conversion time goes down by 22%, how's that only a little?

Comment: You are right, ***little*** was an exaggeration. The conversion time is not stable; as I find, the shortest time I see is **11 ms**, same as `rsYuvToRGBA_uchar4`. The experiment with `rsYuvToRGBA_uchar4` shows that both parts, retrieving YUV and conversion, could be optimized.

Comment: Only thing I would try out of couriosity is using clamp instead of your If-else blocks. But I suppose that won't make a big or any difference. Unfortunately I don't know of any other improvements.

Comment: It's weird, but my compiler was not ready to accept `clamp()` in the first place; maybe, it's time to look for the cause. Also, could it be that the OS decided to run my custom function on CPU? And may there be a way to advise it to run on GPU? I will try `#pragma rs_fp_imprecise` instead of `rs_fp_relaxed`, maybe it will bring me some luck.

Comment: Regarding the cpu / gpu execution, you can force cpu exection via adb, see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/c83dd0b9f81aaeb15e2d03849b04f20b581bfe49)

Comment: @AccoGuy thank you so much got this insight. I tried the 2x2 matrix (CPU vs GPU, intrinsic vs scriptC), and the results are awesome; see update.

Comment: @AlexChon since the behavior is a litte weird, did you make sure you really get the time when the kernel execution is finished (`ForEach()` is not a blocking call)

Comment: @AccoGuy that's another very good point. I have added `rs.finish()` and updated the table.

Comment: @AlexChon By accident I found that within the debug log you can see a [RS-DIAG] tag, which is posting where the kernels are launched (gpu or cpu). Unfortunately that output is only generated while running a androidTest for me (android 9 device).